# How to optimistically call a Uniswap method?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, uni

I'm trying to calculate the price for a Uniswap pair before paying.  In their docs, there's a `Quoter` contract that gives you this information, but it has this warning at the top:

```
These functions are not gas efficient and should not be called on chain. Instead, optimistically execute the swap and check the amounts in the callback.
```

I don't understand what "optimistically execute the swap" means.